# Show keyboard on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to test ime option using my emulator, but I can not see the keyboard. I can type letters, but I need the keyboard just like in a real android device. How can I do that? I was trying to find something in settings, but I can't find anything.
Look:

[image]

Comment: Go to Android Virtual Device Manager and edit your emulator. Tick Hardware keyboard present. Then run avd again.

Comment: Do you mean "Hardware keyboard present" should be unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned by [@sanat shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024527/sanat-shukla) you have to edit your Android Virtual Device (AVD) in the AVD manager. You have to tick off the "Hardware keyboard present". That means the emulator will not use the Hardware keyboard, but show you a Software keyboard.

More information: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps, if you are using Android Studio:

**1.** Goto your AVD Manager

**2.** Select your device

**3.** Click on the *edit* button

**4.** Now Click on *Show Advance Settings*

**5.** Scroll down to the option to disable(as you want to disable) **Enable Keyboard Input**